# Use map and filter to handle items with same value

Tags: javascript

In the example below, I have an array of objects which contain some basic information about films - a film name and a personal rating.

Then i'm returning the duplicate values (using map and filter) to return new arrays and I can then count the number of items in that new array.

```
let films = [{
    "name": "film 1",
    "rating": "5",
}, {
    "name": "film 2",
    "rating": "1",
}, {
    "name": "film 3",
    "rating": "2",
}, {
    "name": "film 4",
    "rating": "2",
}, {
    "name": "film 5",
    "rating": "5",
}, {
    "name": "film 6",
    "rating": "4",
}];

let ratingsArray = films.map((element, i) => {
    return element.rating;
})
let arr0 = ratingsArray.filter((rating) => {
    return rating == 0;
})
let arr1 = ratingsArray.filter((rating) => {
    return rating == 1;
})
let arr2 = ratingsArray.filter((rating) => {
    return rating == 2;
})
let arr3 = ratingsArray.filter((rating) => {
    return rating == 3;
})
let arr4 = ratingsArray.filter((rating) => {
    return rating == 4;
})
let arr5 = ratingsArray.filter((rating) => {
    return rating == 5;
});

console.log(arr0);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
console.log(arr4);
console.log(arr5);
```

This does actually work but it seems a very repetitive way of writing this code.

Can anyone please suggest a better that I could be doing this?

Comment: do you want only the ratings in the arrays, not the whole objects?

Comment: At first look, `let arr0 = films.filter((film) => {
    return film.rating == 0;
})`, should return all the films with 0 rating. You could wrap it around with a function that takes rating as an arguement

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object and group the objects by rating.

```js
var films = [{ name: "film 1", rating: "5", }, { name: "film 2", rating: "1", }, { name: "film 3", rating: "2", }, { name: "film 4", rating: "2", }, { name: "film 5", rating: "5", }, { name: "film 6", rating: "4", }],
    ratings = Object.create(null);

films.forEach(o => (ratings[o.rating] = ratings[o.rating] || []).push(o));

console.log(ratings);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that you can use as the callback in `filter`. It works similarly to how lodash's `pluck` method worked. `pluck` accepts a property key, and value and returns a closure that's used as the callback function when `filter` iterates over the elements in the array.

```js
let films = [
  { "name": "film 1", "rating": "5" }, 
  { "name": "film 2", "rating": "1" }, 
  { "name": "film 3", "rating": "2" },
  { "name": "film 4", "rating": "2" },
  { "name": "film 5", "rating": "5" },
  { "name": "film 6", "rating": "4" }
];

function pluck(key, value) {
  return function (el) {
    return el[key] === value;
  }
}

const rating4 = films.filter(pluck('rating', '2'));
console.log(rating4);
```

You can then use this as you see fit, whether you want to loop over a set of ratings and store that information in an object, for example, but this is completely up to you. And you can use this function not just on this data set, but all sets where you need to pull out this kind of data.

```js
let characters = [{
    "name": "Batman",
    "age": 62
}, {
    "name": "Supergirl",
    "age": 27
}, {
    "name": "Tarzan",
    "age": 102
}];

function pluck(key, value) {
  return function (el) {
    return el[key] === value;
  }
}

const tarzan = characters.filter(pluck('age', 102));
console.log(tarzan);
```

One thing tho: you might benefit from having the ratings as integers rather than strings. One thing to consider moving forward.

Comment: lodash doesn't have `_.pluck` anymore, they just say to use `_.filter`

Comment: So what you're saying is my answer is _better_ than lodash?

Comment: Not necessarily (since you ask): I don't think your `pluck` function adds much value.  Lodash got rid of `_.pluck` in favor of the more gernal `_.filter`  I don't think they are meant to be used in combination as you do.  My opinion, but you asked.

Comment: Well, it was sarcasm masked as a rhetorical question. But since the OP _isn't_ using lodash (who loads a library for one method -  I mentioned it passing) I disagree that my code doesn't add value. It's functional which means it can be used for similar datasets where you need to filter data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grouping the films by rating you can do using a object and arrays to store. See the example bellow:

```js
let films = [{
    "name": "film 1",
    "rating": "5",
}, {
    "name": "film 2",
    "rating": "1",
}, {
    "name": "film 3",
    "rating": "2",
}, {
    "name": "film 4",
    "rating": "2",
}, {
    "name": "film 5",
    "rating": "5",
}, {
    "name": "film 6",
    "rating": "4",
}];
var filmsByRating = {};
//group films by rating
films.forEach((film) => {
   if(!filmsByRating[film.rating])
      filmsByRating[film.rating] = [];
   filmsByRating[film.rating].push(film);
});
//print ratings and films
for(var i in filmsByRating){
  console.log("Rating:", i);
  console.log(filmsByRating[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to combine concepts from other answers and suggestions therein, and generate an `Array`, using `reduce`.  Some advantages of putting the ratings into an `Array` instead of an `Object` include that you will then be able to perform useful `Array` methods such as `reverse` or (custom) `sort` e.g. maybe you want to sort by the rating that has the most films associated with it.

```
var films = [
    { name: "film 1", rating: "5", }, 
    { name: "film 2", rating: "1", }, 
    { name: "film 3", rating: "2", }, 
    { name: "film 4", rating: "2", }, 
    { name: "film 5", rating: "5", }, 
    { name: "film 6", rating: "4", }
];

var ratings = films.reduce(function(result, film) {
    var rating = parseInt(film.rating, 10);
    var ratedFilms = result[rating] || [];
    ratedFilms.push(film);
    result[rating] = ratedFilms;
    return result;
}, []);

ratings.forEach(function(rating, i) {
    console.log(i + ": " + JSON.stringify(rating));
});
```

RESULT:

```
1: [{"name":"film 2","rating":"1"}]
2: [{"name":"film 3","rating":"2"},{"name":"film 4","rating":"2"}]
4: [{"name":"film 6","rating":"4"}]
5: [{"name":"film 1","rating":"5"},{"name":"film 5","rating":"5"}]
```